# C++: Iterate Through Map

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11

I'm trying to iterate through a map to read out a string and then all of the numbers in a vector to a file. I copied and pasted the typedef line, then adjusted it to my code, so I'm not positive it's correct. Anyways, Visual Studio is giving me errors on the use of iterator_variable in my loops. It says type name is not allowed. How can I fix this?

```
ofstream output("output.txt");
typedef map<string, vector<int>>::iterator iterator_variable;
for (iterator_variable iterator = misspelled_words.begin(); iterator != misspelled_words.end(); iterator++)
{
    output << iterator_variable->first;
    for (int i = 0; i < misspelled_words.size(); i++)
    {
        output << " " << iterator_variable->second[i];
    }
    output << endl;
}
```

Comment: As the error says, `iterator_variable` is a type, replace it with the name of the variable `iterator` within the body of the `for`. The inner `for` is suspicious too. Are you sure you want to loop over `[0, misspelled_words.size()]` instead of `[0, iterator->second.size())`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should access the iterator like `iterator->first` instead of `iterator_variable->first`.

And for the inner loop, you probably want to iterate through 0 to `iterator->second.size()` instead of  `misspelled_words.size()`.

```
ofstream output("output.txt");
typedef map<string, vector<int>>::iterator iterator_variable;
for (iterator_variable iterator = misspelled_words.begin(); iterator != misspelled_words.end(); iterator++)
{
    output << iterator->first;
    for (int i = 0; i < iterator->second.size(); i++)
    {
        output << " " << iterator->second[i];
    }
    output << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the the new range based for loop and auto for more concise and readable code too.

```
ofstream output("output.txt");
for ( auto const & ref: misspelled_words ) {
    output << ref.first;
    for (auto const & ref2 : ref.second ) {
        output << " " << ref2;
    }
    output << "\n"; // endl force a stream flush and slow down things.
}
```